# The minimum value of $\frac{a^3 + b^3 + c^3 }{\sqrt{a^4 + b^4 + c^4 }}$ . When $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1 $

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inequality

Asume $a, b, c $ is non-negative real.
I got above equation at this situation ;

$\vec {x}= (a, b, c)$ , 
$\vec {y} = (a^2 , b^2 , c^2 ) $

$$ cos \phi = \frac{ \vec x \cdot \vec {y}} { \Vert {\vec {x} \Vert} \times\Vert {\vec {y} \Vert}} = \frac{ a^3 + b^3 + c^3 } { \sqrt{ a^4 + b^4 + c^4 }}$$
In this case I want to know the Maximum value of $\phi$ .
But I can't compute. 
I want your help.

Comment: Are you familiar with Lagrange multipliers? If not, here's the crash course: note that you have a function $F$ to minimize and a condition $G=1$ for some function $G$. So, at a maxima $F-\lambda \cdot (G-1)=0$. You need another condition though for a unique result. Otherwise, try $a=b=c$?

Comment: Thanks your comments, I am sorry but I don't understand your words.

Comment: The minimum you seek is the root of $72 x^8-584 x^6+1728 x^4-1944 x^2+729$ close to $0.9576$ so the max angle is $\approx 16.75^\circ$, though not find a simpler way than uvw to get the minimum.

Answer (score 5):

Let the minimum be $m$.  Then we have the homogeneous symmetric inequality 
$$(a^3+b^3+c^3)^2 \geqslant m^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^4+b^4+c^4)$$

Using $a+b+c = 3u, ab+bc+ca = 3v^2, abc = w^3$, the above reduces to a quadratic in terms of $w^3$ with positive leading term, so the inequality will hold if it holds for  $b=c=1$ and $b=1, c=0  {(\star)}$ .  Thus it is enough to have the following satisfied for $a \in \mathbb R^+$:
$$\frac{a^3+2}{\sqrt{(a^2+2)(a^4+2)}} ,  \frac{a^3+1}{\sqrt{(a^2+1)(a^4+1)}} \geqslant m$$
It turns out the more restrictive condition is the left most, so we find using single variable calculus the minima for $\dfrac{a^3+2}{\sqrt{(a^2+2)(a^4+2)}}$, which is your best $m \approx 0.9576$.

---

*P.S.:  There is a third condition $(\star)$ as the quadratic minimum could be at a stationary point, and while it is not restrictive in this case, it is not as easily tractable as the others and is omitted above.*

Comment: $b=c=1$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$???

Comment: @QuangHoang Once you homogenise, you can throw away the constraint...

Comment: Thank you, Macavity . This problem is very difficult for me.

Comment: @SwonyLee  Above is not a very satisfactory solution, though I am not sure if it gets simpler.  Cant see a useful geometric interpretation either.  Lagrange clearly would be more readily mechanical but the resulting equations may be very cumbersome. Lets hope someone has a better way.

Comment: At first I think $P$ is on the sphere, radius 1 and origin centerd. and $Q$ is on the plane $ x+y+z =1$. I want to know some function $f:P(a,b,c) -> Q(a^2,b^2 c^2)$ in geometrically. Anyway,,Thanks Mac...!

Comment: Could you please explain your statement "using $a+b+c = 3u, ab+bc+ca = 3v^2, abc = w^3$, the above reduces to a quadratic in terms of $w^3$ with positive leading term, so the inequality will hold if it holds for  $b=c=1$ and $b=1, c=0  {(\star)}$"? Thank you.

Comment: @Hans that's a fair bit to explain. Perhaps you could go through http://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php?id=YXR0YWNobWVudHMvOC9lLzI3MDMzM2NkNjI5ODFlMmIyMzg4NmYwYWYwMzAzZjQ2YWM4ODRj&rn=VGhlIHV2dyBtZXRob2QucGRm and I can clarify any residual question.

Comment: The article you cited is very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I think that Macavity gave a good answer.

1. I would add a remark which could hide a geometrical property.

EDIT. The minimum of the function $f:a\rightarrow \dfrac{a^3+2}{\sqrt{(a^2+2)(a^4+2)}}$ is reached in $a_0$ satisfying $a_0^4-2a_0^3-4a_0+2=0$. It is easy to see that $a_0$ can be constructed with rule and compass over $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/3})$ ($a_0$ is constructible if we have the length $3^{1/3}$). We have to normalize $a_0,b_0=c_0=1$. An admissible solution is $a_1=\dfrac{a_0}{\sqrt{a_0^2+2}}\approx 0.871,b_1=c_1=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a_0^2+2}}\approx 0.347$; the minimal polynomial of $a_1$ is $p(u)=9u^8-12u^6+18u^4-12u^2+1$ and of $b_1=c_1$ is $q(u)=36u^8-48u^6+36u^4-12u^2+1$.

Then $\cos(\phi_1)=g(a_1,b_1,c_1)=\dfrac{a_1^3+b_1^3+c_1^3}{\sqrt{a_1^4+b_1^4+c_1^4}}$ and $\phi_1$ are also constructible under the same conditions.

2. With the essential help of Maple, I solved the problem using the Lagrange method. We seek the critical points of $g^2(a,b,c)$ under the constraints $a^2+b^2+c^2=1,a,b,c\geq 0$.

Case 1. We are not on the edge of the domain. We obtain after eliminating $c$ and the Lagrange's variable:

i) a degenerate curve $\Gamma$: $2a^6+3a^4b^2+2a^3b^3+3a^2b^4+2b^6-3a^4-6a^2b^2-3b^4+3a^2+3b^2-1=0$.

A numerical calculation shows that the minimum on $\Gamma$ is reached in points as $a \approx 0.659306, b\approx 0.315378$ and is $\approx 0.98611>0.9576$.

After eliminating $b$ (resp. $a$), we find the equation in $a$ (resp. $b$):

ii) $p(a)q(a)(3a^2-1)(12a^{12}-24a^{10}+24a^8-24a^6+15a^4-6a^2+1)=0$.

$a=\pm 1/\sqrt{3}$ implies $a=b=c$ and $\phi=0$. The last factor gives also a maximum ($\cos(\phi)=1$). Finally, we find the solution above ($p(a)=0$ or $q(a)=0$).

Case 2. We are on the edge of the domain. For example $a=0$. After eliminating $c$ and the Lagrange's variable, we obtain (for $b$ or $c$):

$b(b-1)(b+1)(2b^2-1)(b^4-b^2+1)(4b^8-8b^6+12b^4-8b^2+1)=0$.

Only the last factor gives a local minimum: $b_2\approx 0.3992179614,c_2\approx .9168560516$ and $g(0,b_2,c_2)\approx 0.9751727510>0.9576$.